# How to auto-format C# code generated by a .tt file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4

I assume there's some kind of IDE service object that can auto-format the generated .cs file(s) from a .tt file after it's done being generated, but I can't find it.

Because right now I have fully working auto-generated code of 12k mis-aligned and very hard to read lines, and it would be *nice* if I could format them nicely, like CTRL-K-D / CTRL-E-D does.

Comment: Those keystrokes will work on the generated files. The changes will be lost once the file is regenerated though. Are you asking how to format each time they are regenerated?

Comment: Yes. I don't want to do it manually just to lose it the next time I update the .tt file.

Comment: This is the wrong approach. Try to account for your spacing chars in the template and seeing how the output is changed. Try not to use tabs and instead focus on spaces. That way your output is more uniform and you won't need to Ctrl-K-D once the file is generated.